# C# How to trim both whitespace character and other character

Tags: c#

I want to trim leading whitespace and the single quote using one call to Trim without calling it twice as follows.

```
string s = "    'hello'";
var newString = s.Trim().Trim('\'');
```

I don't want to use

```
var newString = s.TrimStart().Trim(''\').
```

either as it is two calls.

Comment: _"leading whitespace"_ means you want to use [`TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question. +1 to compensate for downvote.

Comment: Fair enough, but I didn't see a close vote for the dupe, or a comment to that effect.  I found the question valuable, since, in all these years of coding C# I had never hit upon Trim() having parms -- never needed it, I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [overload of `Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts multiple characters:

```
string s = "    'hello'";
var newString = s.Trim(' ', '\'');
```

Although there are several caveats:

- your question only mentions *leading* whitespace, but `Trim` removes *trailing* characters as well.  If you only want *leading* characters use `TrimStart` instead.
- this solution only removes *full spaces*, not all *whitespace*.  Technically you would have to add all [characters that are considered "whitespace"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netframework-4.7). If you need to trim more than just spaces, then calling `Trim` twice will be cleaner.
- This solution would also Trim whitespace *within the apostrophes*:

  ```
  string s = "  '  hello'";
  var newString = s.Trim(' ', '\'');   // returns "hello"
  ```

Comment: Actually this didn't work because in my case the leading characters are tabs and perhaps other whitespace characters. I needed something that represented the equivalent of Trim(). I suppose I could add all whitespace characters?

Comment: @user2449323 Sure (there are 25 of them according to the link in my answer), or just specify tab or just call `Trim` twice (which would be cleaner IMHO than specifying 25 characters to trim).

Comment: Calling Trim twice doesn't work either if your string starts with  `- - - -` or something.  You'd have to stick it in a loop and check if it still needs to be trimmed of all chars.  Trim should allow for a whitespace escape char like Regex's `\s`